# Problems with transposition of cell values in Excel

Tags: excel, formulas

Is a question about excel. I should repeat horizontally (on the second sheet of the same file), the cell values that are arranged vertically. Also, when I'm going to change the values of the "source" cells, I would like the values to automatically update on the second sheet.
Since the cells to be transposed are so many, I would like to ensure that the transposition starts from the first column (from the first sheet), then the second column and so on.. because I noticed that instead of continuing with the second column, the transposition goes to the second line.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have values in `Sheet1` in `Column A` vertically as below,

[image]

Enter the formula in your other sheet in cell `A1`, and drag it to the right and then down,

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,COLUMN()-1,ROW()-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Excel says the formula contains an error, and highlights a part of the formula: https://pasteboard.co/9esVzxt7Q.png

Comment: Unfortunately there are still problems. "The formula contains unrecognized text" https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjhjy.png

Comment: My version is in Italian. However, the problem persists even if I replace the equivalents of my language. It may be that I did not understand the formula well. Can you explain me?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. Yes, the problem went away by replacing respectively INDICE and RIF.COLONNA

Comment: There is only one problem. If I drag the formula to the other cells, the formula manages to transpose horizontally, only the cells of the first column (of the first sheet), and then always transpose the same cells on the second row, on the second sheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5X4d.png

Comment: I should transpose horizontally, hundreds of values, arranged vertically. The problem is that the sheet is quite complex.

Comment: thank you so much. If you like, we can also open a chat

Comment: Maybe I did not understand what I should write in parentheses, after RIF.COLONNA

Comment: @user63747 I have updated the answer. I leave it to you to convert `OFFSET` `ROW` and `COLUMN` to italian version

Comment: Yes, it works now. I wanted to understand what "Sheet1! $A$1" is, To see if I can use the formula anywhere or only if I start from the first row or column.

Comment: It has to be the first value of that table.

Comment: Yes. I tried to write other values in the first sheet. The values start from cell H25. Then the formula becomes =SCARTO(Sheet1!$H$25;RIF.COLONNA()-1;RIF.RIGA()-1) If I paste this formula on the first cell of the affected sheet, and then I drag it on the other cells, it all works. But if the formula starts at any other point, nothing works.

Comment: I think I need to change / personalize RIF.COLONNA() and RIF.RIGA()

Comment: exactly. you have to increase the `-1` to some other value if you start from some other cell and not `A1`

Comment: Are we talking about the sheet in which I will go to display the values? We assume that the "source" values start from cell H25 (Sheet1) and the values to be displayed must start from cell J26 (Sheet3), how will the formula become?

Comment: =SCARTO(Sheet1!$H$25;RIF.COLONNA()-10;RIF.RIGA()-26) But should I put it manually? Is there a way to just click on the cell where I want to start the formula?

Comment: This formula works =SCARTO(Sheet1!$H$25;RIF.COLONNA()-RIF.COLONNA($J$26);RIF.RIGA()-RIF.RIGA($J$26)) But it does not seem very comfortable

Comment: try this `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,COLUMN(A:A)-1,ROW(1:1)-1)`. this should work anywhere in the sheet

Comment: perfect. it works. The only thing I have to change is `Sheet1!$A$1` The rest of the formula can stay unchanged, right?